# Execute event from code

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

Im trying to reuse a code that i've made for toggleswitch on my application

When the switch is unchecked it fires the code below

```
private void ToggleSwitch_Unchecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   //Some code here YAY!
}
```

Works like a charm from the XAML.

```
<toolkit:ToggleSwitch Margin="0,0,12,0" Content="Allow" Checked="ToggleSwitch_Checked" Unchecked="ToggleSwitch_Unchecked" x:Name="allowGpsSwitch" IsChecked="true" />
```

Now im trying to call this code from C# as well. I tried a few ways of calling ToggleSwitch_Unchecked code without success.

In resume: I want to call ToggleSwitch_Unchecked from code to execute right away. I know i can make a method for that separately but i want o reuse the same one i made for the event.

is it possible or my thoughts are completely wrong?

Comment: well you should say why/how does it fail if you call it from code passing this and EventArgs.Empty for example. In general I do create a small private method and call it from the event handler and from code. In some cases this is a bit more complicated than that if your inner method needs to use the event arguments because then what do you pass when calling it from code?!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, I think your thoughts are wrong. Your method signature for an event handler includes arguments that you would not need in other contexts. Why not structure as follows:

```
private void ToggleSwitch_Unchecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   DoSomething()
}

private void DoSomething()
{
   // ...
}
```

You can then execute `DoSomething` whenever you like!

Comment: thanks. thats what i thought would be the correct way just needed a confirmation.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't use `(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)` arguments values  then you really should make a new method out of `//Some code here YAY!` part and call it from `ToggleSwitch_Unchecked` as well as from any other point you want to use it at.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you should be able to call it with null and EventArgs.Empty:

```
ToggleSwitch_Unchecked(null, EventArgs.Empty);
```

or with null, null

```
ToggleSwitch_Unchecked(null, null);
```

but it depends whether you need to use `sender` and `e`.

Comment: no, he should pass this and EventArgs.Empty instead of null, null

Comment: thank you. null, null works actually. EventArgs.Empty wont compile, says i have invalid arguments. Either way i think @ColinE answer is better for this case.